# Leaflet - how can I change the grabbing hand cursor?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mouse-cursor

I've probably overlooked how to change LeftletJS's cursor when on the map.  http://leafletjs.com/reference.htm

I've tried setting `map_div.style.cursor = 'crosshair';` - this works on other elements, but not on the map div.  I assume this is because Leaflet is overriding it in some way.

I want to be able to switch to the "crosshair" cursor with Javascript (and back).

Is this possible?

Update: I don't have jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't override because the object doesn't have support:
[image]

Solution---after creating your map use either

JQuery

```
$('.leaflet-container').css('cursor','crosshair');
```

or

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('map').style.cursor = 'crosshair'
document.getElementById('map').style.cursor = '' //(reset)
```

You can also use this event to change your mouse:

```
map_div.on('mousedown', function (e) {})
```

Comment: How is this different from what I was trying?  (I don't have jQuery, so I need to use the DOM methods.)

Comment: document.getElementById('map').style.cursor = 'crosshair'

Answer (score 5):

You only need to override the Leaflet's cursor styles. Following example overrides the default cursor:

```
.leaflet-grab {cursor: auto;}
```

This one changes the cursor when you're dragging the map:

```
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-grab {cursor: move;}
```

Live sample: [Change default Leaflet cursors](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBzZpR)

Comment: Nice demo, strange behavior on my map; move cursor only appears after finishing the move (and letting go of the mouse)